# Looks like my jquery slider has some bug in setting the slider to some value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery slider in my webpage.

I am using the following jquery

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/ui/ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/ui/ui.slider.min.js"></script>
```

when the page loads i try to set the value of the slider to a specific position like below

```
 $('#changeTableSlider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: 4,
    change: function(e, ui){
            .... 
    },
});
```

but what i have noticed is that the slider is not setting is position to value 4 but it's at 0 when the page is rendered. How I can solve this jquery problem...?I have no permission to change jquery version. Is there any simple css slider avaiable.?

Comment: Your code looks fine, perhaps it would help if you could post a more complete code listing or example?

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI is that? is it compatible with jQuery 1.2.6?

Comment: I see a trailing comma in your example after `change:function{}`

Comment: it's 1.8.11 jquery UI version. I don't know if it's compatible with jquery 1.2.6...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a silly answer/question, but have you wrapped your code in ths ....?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```